# comparing 2 cell formula and getting either 1 cell value or get value of 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

can anyone advise the following formula,

cell A = a value

cell b = a value

wanting the formula at cell c.

if cell A > cell b, will use cell A value,

if cell A < cell B , will use 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple IF function should do the trick.

`=IF(A1>B1,A1,0)`

You haven't specified an outcome for the equal scenario though. So you could replace `>` with `>=` if it should be A1, or leave as-is for 0.

Comment: thank you very much , i needed just this.